# Looking at a Career jump into DevOps and advice or suggested reading

Tags: culture, learning

I've been in various facets of Software development over the past 10+ years. I started in the development side of the Application Lifecycle Management(= ALM) cycle, and more recently I've been working in the QA side of ALM.

One thing that has consistently bothered me was all the different companies that I've worked for tried to embrace an effective ALM process but in the end it usually turned out to be a half-baked implementation of a scrum methodology that had all the different team leads debating about the right and wrong ways to implement ALM processes.

I've been currently researching DevOps in hopes that I can shift my career to a direction that will allow me to better contribute to a companies ALM process.

I have quite a bit of experience in Dev, QA, and General IT but I wouldn't consider myself an absolute expert in either area.

Any suggestions, advice, recommended reading, etc?

If you recommend a book could you include the ISBN number (it's easier to search for it that way).

Comment: Welcome! This question is a little broad for the site (take a look at the [tour] and [ask]); advice doesn't really work so well in our format. You can [edit] to narrow your question down a little bit, or perhaps ask in [chat]. Maybe narrowing your question down to just employment or recommended reading, rather than both, would work better. Good luck!

Comment: If you've got the basics of dev, QA, and IT, but aren't an expert in any of them... you're the very model of a modern major DevOps engineer already. Jack of all trades, master of none is pretty much the definition.

Comment: Please include a link to what ALM means, or explain.  Pretty sure a lot of people don't know what it is. :)

Answer (score 5):

I do not think that there is a single correct piece of advice for such a broad question, but here are my thoughts your situation:

**As a starting point** look at your current workflow, processes, and technologies being used at the company and then research some tools
*(Jenkins, Kubernetes, Docker, Grafana, Ansible, Kubana etc)*
or techniques(writing your own scripts or programs) that might be useful to your company or any projects you are working on.

I would also suggest maybe attending local DevOps meetups or talks in your area for more exposure.

Answer (score 5):

Google's [SRE book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920041528.do) would be a good start.

I would also pick a configuration management system like [ansible](/questions/tagged/ansible) or [chef](/questions/tagged/chef) and practice with it.  Maybe use it to setup your next desktop or server.

Answer (score 1):

The Phoenix Project is one of the best book to read about DevOps and their is one very interesting community driven website devopsuniversity.org they are also updating interesting material on DevOps to start with.